# How to show one entity which has 2 categories in an ER diagram?

Tags: database, erd

I need to draw an ER diagram for a school project for an online learning platform. It has an entity called module, and there are 2 types of modules; compulsory and elective, since elective modules which are taken by each student can be identified by the degree programme entity, elective modules cannot hence arising the need for a way to identify the 2 types of modules separately.
Another option is to identify each student from the modules taken by them, where the degree program can then be traced back to from the module id.
I want to know if there is a way to identify the 2 module types separately.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to make tables named:

1. module(id,name,moduletype_id)
2. moduletype(id,name)
3. Student
4. degreeprogram (related to modules m-m)
5. a few more to not solve your complete exercise.